# Aptana 3 > key bindings > move 1 character left or right missing?

Tags: aptana, key-bindings

I was trying to bind the following commands to keys:

- Move right one character
- Move left one character
- Select next character
- Select previous character

But I can't find those anywhere under Preferences > Keys.

Is it possible to bind those commands somehow?

It would be really nice to not have to switch to the cursor keys for moving around.

Thx for your help in advance.

Hubisan